# What will happen if I drag partition C:\ to partition D:\?

Tags: windows

I dare not carry out this experiment,but want to know the result very much,anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows (atleast Vista and 7) will create a shortcut to C:\ folder in D:\ folder if you drag C:\ folder in Windows Explorer on top of D:\ folder.

Comment: +1 Yes. that is true :) But I was kind of scared so I tried dragging D over E... :P

Comment: Ha ha. Me too. But I was gonna format my PC anyway; hence the bravery. :)

Comment: True for XP too..

Comment: Heard of VMs?

Comment: Sure. But didn't have one at the time.